# Django custom forms Dynamic Raw Id

Tags: python, django, forms, model, foreign-keys

I have a table with a foreign key. My problem is that ther's a lot of registers, so I need do that:

[image]

But all I've found was for the Admin Panel. Any idea for a custom form without admin?

Comment: Are you asking how to implement a form outside of Django Admin?

Comment: No, most likely the search button where the big arrow is pointing to, surrounded by a near perfect circle in the same colour. Clicking that creates a pop-up with clickable model instances and when clicked sticks the id into the field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raw id, isn't needed any more, since there's autocomplete in the admin. This is also the solution for a model in the frontend. However, you should not bake it yourself, but just use [Django Autocomplete Light](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light/). An excerpt from [the tutorial](https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html#overview):

> Autocompletes are based on 3 moving parts:
>
> - widget compatible with the model field, does the initial rendering,
> - javascript widget initialization code, to trigger the autocomplete,
> - and a view used by the widget script to get results from.

Comment: Thank you so much, that's what I need.

Comment: Raw id are still needed if the list is really long. when using the admin autocomplete, it will be very slow and might jam the server.